# Validating JSON request in Interceptor vs in Controller

Tags: json, spring, rest, web-services, validation

I recently started working on Rest Based Web services. Here I have a requirement where I need to validate the contents of the request based on a parameter of request.

My question is What will be the best approach to do this validation.
I have two different JSON requests hitting my webservice.

1. Validate in the interceptor. This will need me to cast the request object back to its actual Type.
2. Validating the request in Controller.

Also I would like to know if filters can be used in this scenario and what benefit will it give me.

Thanks.

Comment: if you want to do this check in every(or so many) request use `interceptor` , otherwise do it in controller

Comment: what is the reason for using interceptor over controller?

Comment: Interceptor- a single code for all request.  controller- same code needs to be repeated in every controller which is weird